# curl and get_file_contents don't work with parameters on url

Tags: php

I'm trying to write a php script that is able to gather data from web sites. My problem is with  file_get_contents and curl funcitons: I need to get the html of the url http://www.booking.com/searchresults.it.html?city=-121726;rows=20;offset=20 that is the second page of the list of hotels in Milano. What I get is allways the first page of the list, as if I get it from offset=0 ! As you can easy verify, the above url works fine in any browser,  showing the second page of hotel list! The problem is only with both curl and file_get_contents functions! Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

try with this url
http://www.booking.com/searchresults.it.html?city=-121726&rows=20&offset=20

i already have done a crawler for booking.com, what a coincidence

Comment: Thanks... but still doesn't work. I use this simple code to test:  <?php
$inx='http://www.booking.com/searchresults.it.html?city=-121726&rows=20&offset=20';
$st = file_get_contents($inx);
echo $st;
?>

Comment: you have to use curl, and send all the required headers

Comment: Thanks Amez! You are right! I forgot to specify the user agent! Now it works fine!